# cant load google maps in magento 2.4 nginx

Tags: javascript, magento2.4, google-map

I cant load google maps in magento 2.4.
I am using nginx as webserver and running the project in http => port 80
when I add google maps script

```
require([
    "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<?= /** @noEscape */ $apiKey ?>&libraries=places&v=weekly&language=fr"
], function () {
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: { lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195 },
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: "roadmap",
    });
    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    const input = document.getElementById("pac-input");
    const searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener("bounds_changed", () => {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    let markers = [];

    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener("places_changed", () => {
        const places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach((marker) => {
            marker.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];

        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        places.forEach((place) => {
            if (!place.geometry || !place.geometry.location) {
                console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
                return;
            }

            const icon = {
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25),
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    map,
                    icon,
                    title: place.name,
                    position: place.geometry.location,
                })
            );
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                // Only geocodes have viewport.
                bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });

    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener("places_changed", () => {
        const places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach((marker) => {
            marker.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];

        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        places.forEach((place) => {
            if (!place.geometry || !place.geometry.location) {
                console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
                return;
            }

            const icon = {
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25),
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    map,
                    icon,
                    title: place.name,
                    position: place.geometry.location,
                })
            );
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                // Only geocodes have viewport.
                bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
});
```

I get an error message in browser console

> [Report Only] Refused to load the script 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttp%3A%2F%2Fmagento-front-marjane.com%2Ffr%2Fmultishipping%2Fcheckout_address%2FnewShipping%2F&4sAIzaSyDeEulUN4YxahgSWg-1xdz9ddAcCyHcp-Q&callback=*xdc*._1e0egw&key=AIzaSyDeEulUN4YxahgSWg-1xdz9ddAcCyHcp-Q&token=12865' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src assets.adobedtm.com secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net [www.googleadservices.com](http://www.googleadservices.com) [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com) [www.paypalobjects.com](http://www.paypalobjects.com) js.braintreegateway.com [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com) geostag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com geoapi.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafapi.cardinalcommerce.com songbird.cardinalcommerce.com includestest.ccdc02.com [www.sandbox.paypal.com](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com) t.paypal.com s.ytimg.com video.google.com vimeo.com [www.vimeo.com](http://www.vimeo.com) [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) *.trackedlink.net *.trackedweb.net *.dotdigital-pages.com cdn.dnky.co api.comapi.com webchat.dotdigital.com *.google.com *.fontawesome.com *.googletagmanager.com *.gstatic.com *.facebook.net *.doubleclick.net *.bing.com *.ads-twitter.com https://www.googletagmanager.com tagmanager.google.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: That is only a report and Google Maps is not being blocked. If Google maps isn't loading for you then it's most likely an issue with the JS you have written.

Comment: I found that there is a configuration in magento called csp_whitelist.xml added <values>
                    <value id="google-maps" type="host">*.maps.googleapis.com</value></values> in each policy item, now the autocomplete  is work but the map doesnt show up in the mage

Comment: I am getting this error message only  "common.js:45 [Report Only] Refused to load the script 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttp%3A%2F%2Fmagento-front-marjane.com%2Ffr%2Fmultishipping%2Fcheckout_address%2FnewShipping%2F&4sAIzaSyDeEulUN4YxahgSWg-1xdz9ddAcCyHcp-Q&callback=_xdc_._1e0egw&key=AIzaSyDeEulUN4YxahgSWg-1xdz9ddAcCyHcp-Q&token=12865' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src-elem *.maps.googleapis.com"."

Comment: Look at the first 2 words in the error "[Report Only]". Magento isn't actually blocking the script it just display the report as an error which is very misleading. If you check your network tab you should see a 200 status for the request.

Comment: Some other things to check - Do you have an element with the ID of `map`? If so, is there any HTML in there?

Comment: Also, "Ensure that the div element for the map has a height. By default, div elements are created with a height of 0, and are therefore invisible."

Comment: thanks for your helpe I added the height  on div element that has id => map now the map is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this is to ensure you add a height to the div, as taken from the docs:

> Ensure that the div element for the map has a height. By default, div elements are created with a height of 0, and are therefore invisible.